# Error with kali linux win-dex-install

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, error-handling

I just installed wsl kali Linux on Windows but this error came up while installing win-dex -y command. I need this for class and I can't figure it out. I'm new to Linux and need help, please. What should I do to get this to work? The image attached is what is showing up.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your disk reported an input/output error, and as a response to that, the filesystem went read-only to protect against further data corruption.

But I've understood WSL uses a Virtual Hard Disk as its storage. Maybe the Windows disk the VHD is stored on is full, so the VHD would want to expand but can't?

(A VHD should have a configurable maximum size, but it usually takes up only the amount of space that has actually been used so far. I would expect hitting the maximum size limit to trigger a regular "no free space on this device" error, but the situation might be different if the VHD has not yet reached maximum size but is prevented from growing by the shortage of actual disk space.)

Comment: is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: Do a `wsl --shutdown`, then make sure your Windows disk(s) are not 100% full. Then restart WSL: it should automatically perform a filesystem check automatically at startup. If it fails, it might drop you into a recovery mode, where you can run a manual filesystem check: if you need detailed instructions for that, please *edit your question* to show a `lsblk -o +fstype` output first. If manual filesystem check also fails, you have a problem that needs to be fixed on Windows side - and in Unix&Linux StackExchange, Windows advice is off topic. Please ask in [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com).